# WCF SSL Client certificate error

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, windows-8

In our current project we're using a Tibco/Java webservice from our .NET 4.0/MVC/WCF client. We're using two way authentication. Our certificate is sent in the correct way, and the Tibco server sends back their certificate.

Now this al works in Windows 2008 R2, using Visual Studio 2010/IIsExpress to run the web application. But when using the exact same code on Windows 8/Visual Studio 2012 we're getting a lot of :

> Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority

It used to work fine in Windows 2012 too, but without touching our integration (WCF) code this at first started to happen to my colleague and then on my machine too.

The certificates are installed in the same store as in the Windows 2008 R2 machine, and we also see that the certificate is being used.

To be able to move forward we'll resort to our plan B which is back to using Visual Studio 2010/Windows 2008 R2. So I was hoping someone else experienced the same problem and solved it. So the question is, what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Could be the aspnet/networkservice/whatever user you're using for you AppPool doesn't have permission to read the certificate store?

[Check this article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;901183)

Particularly the "Install the client certificate and grant access for the user account" section.

Comment: I'm running/debugging from Visual Studio 2012 using IISExpress. So the application runs with my own credentials. The strange thing is that it suddenly stopped working. The code didn't change, and in Windows 2008 it's still working correctly.